# How to "resync" commits in GitLab after fetching from remote repository?

Tags: gitlab

I've created GitLab project by cloning remote repository. During a few days my colleagues pushed their commits to the original repository (not GitLab). Now I did 'git fetch --all' from GitLab repository but commits do not show in GitLab web UI. What should I do to resync GitLab project with its repository? Is there rake task for that? I can't simply recreate the project as we already imported issues from an external source, created labels, milestones, etc.

Answer (score 11):

There is no GitLab feature to fetch the upstream updates. What you did was import an already existing repository, and that is a one time feature.

But you can fetch the upstream updates into your local repository, then push them to GitLab. You'll need to add the orginial/upstream repo as a remote to your local repository by running `git remote add upstream {path to original repo}`, then fetch the upstream repos by running `git fetch upstream`, then merge `git merge upstream/master`, then `git push master origin`.

GitHub has a decent help section on [adding the upstream remote](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork), and [doing the merge](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork).

Comment: Thanks. I already solved my problem by manual execution of update hook (commit by commit)

Answer (score 0):

Only the EE version of GitLab has the [repository mirroring feature](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html) which supports automatically pulling down updates from the import source repository.

If you are using the free CE version, you'll have to manually update or create a custom process.